# Fill Formula down to all rows

Tags: excel, vba

Using VBA code, I'm trying to fill a formula in column D2 all the way down the column, to the last row of the table, but, for some reason, it only fills down 53 rows (and then it must loop to all the other sheets and do the same). What am I doing wrong?

```
Sub Step_3()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim N As Long

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        N = Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
        ws.Range("D2:D" & N).Formula = "=C2-E2"
    Next ws
        
End Sub
```

Comment: `ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "E")` probably.

Comment: Also, if the code is in the `ActiveWorkbook`, use `ThisWorkbook` instead.

Comment: It was the ws - thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that using `Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row` without any worksheet parent reference it will always refer to the active sheet and always return the same row.

To fix that we need to prefix the range object with `ws`:

```
N = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
```

So:

```
Sub Step_3()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim N As Long

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    N = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
    ws.Range("D2:D" & N).Formula = "=C2-E2"
Next ws
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Of course, and your method will be quicker, doh! Sorry should I delete my answer?

Comment: The prefix ws fixed it. Thanks so much! :-)

I had to use ActiveWorkbook and not ThisWorkbook, since I use the macro for other workbooks.